# PictureBox performing unwanted scaling C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, scale

I currently have a windows form app with a pictureBox in the middle of it which i am drawing various images too. The images are drawing fine except for the fact that they are all being scaled up by exactly 25%. I should also add that i am drawing everything inside a Paint method, using the PaintEventArgs to get the graphics device.

Ive made sure the SizeMode is set to Normal, ive checked over and over that the scale factor of the graphics object is 1 and all the image objects that i pass to the paint method are of the size they should be, but when they get drawn they are a different size.

I have until now just been calling g.drawImage(image, Rectangle) and passing the width and height of the image as the width and height of the Rectangle so that they are forced to be drawn at the correct size but i feel that this should be a short term fix and i am overlooking something simple.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Code is as follows (only the important bits):

```
public class Level : PictureBox
{
    ...
    private Image image;
    ...

    public Level(TabPage parent, Panel propertiesPanel, ItemManager items, string levelName)
    {
        ...

        image = Image.FromFile(@"Levels/" + levelName);
        Size = image.Size;
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;

        MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(level_MouseClick);
        MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(level_MouseMove);
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(level_Paint);

        Invalidate();
    }

    private void level_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        //With the rectangle fix (drawing to correct size)
        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Size.Width, image.Size.Height));
        ////Without the fix (as i thought it should be be this is where it scales it)
        //g.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));

        drawPlacedItems(g);
        drawItemPreview(g);
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code! I bet you its something simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806366/image-sizing-issue-in-bitmap/16806413#16806413

Comment: @JeremyThompson Editing with the code now. Hopefully there is enough info there to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the `HorizontalResolution` and `VerticalResolution` properties of your image are being applied when you don't want them to, modify your code as per Jeremy's link to [Image sizing issue in bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806366/image-sizing-issue-in-bitmap/16806413#16806413) that ensures that `HorizontalResolution` and `VerticalResolution` are reset or ignored before calling `DrawImage`.